# Maximum number of perfect matchings in a graph of genus $g$ balanced $k$-partite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, perfect-matchings, permanent, genus

What is the maximum number of perfect matchings a genus $g$ balanced $k$-partite graph (number of vertices for each color in all possible $k$-colorings is within a difference of $1$) can have? I am particularly interested in $k=2$.

For planar balanced bipartite graphs (each color has to have same number of vertices assigned) the number of perfect matchings is $2^{O(n)}$ while for genus $\Omega(n^2)$ we can have $2^{\Omega(n\log n)}$. So is maximum number of perfect matchings $2^{O(n\log g)}$ for $k=2$?

Comment: genus alone is not a big obstacle, it appears. e.g. fullerens (particular kind of planar graphs) can have exponentially many perfect matchings : https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.1438

Comment: @DimaPasechnik You dont get the point. Balanced bipartite graphs can have $2^{\Omega(n\log n)}$ perfect matchings however genus needs to be high and if you have planarity you are constrained by $2^{O(n)}$ perfect matchings.

Comment: planar 4-gonal $2k\times 2k$ grids can have exponentially many perfect matchnigs, too - one covers such a grid by $2\times 2$ squares, each containing a 4-gon, so you can switch each of them in 2 different ways.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Do you see difference between $O(n)$ and $\Omega(n\log n)$?

Comment: well, all this got to be mentioned in the question, as motivation...

Comment: of course I do - but this is not a very common knowledge that so many matchings are possible in a planar graph.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Isn't it considered implicit?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Updated problem.

Comment: is it a theorem that super-exponential number of matchings is not possible in a planar graph?

Comment: Forgot the reference but check https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273765/maximum-number-of-perfect-matchings-in-a-planar-graph.

Comment: The (bipartite) hypercube on $N=2^n$ vertices has genus $1+(n-4)2^{n-3} \approx C N \log(N)$, and it has roughly $2^{c N \log(\log(N))}$ perfect matchings.  So there’s something with not huge genus having superexponentialy many perfect matchings.

Comment: @PatDevlin $2^{cN\log\log N}=2^{o(n\log g)}$ and so not a counter example.

Comment: If $g = n^\epsilon$, then your claimed upper bound holds since $n \log(g) = \epsilon n \log(n)$ and the complete graph has $2^{O(n \log(n)}$ perfect matchings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not for a great reason.

**Fact:** genus of a graph is bounded below by $|E|/6 - n/2+1$.

**Case 1:** suppose $|E| \leq 10 n$.  Then the number of perfect matchings is at most ${ {|E|} \choose {n/2}} \leq 2^{|E|} \leq 2^{10n}.$

**Case 2:** suppose $|E| \geq 10n$ so that (by fact) the genus satisfies $g \geq n$.  We know every graph has at most $2^{O(n \log(n))}$ perfect matchings, and we’re done since $g\geq n$.

Comment: Yes...  If $g=\log(n)$, then there are at most $10n$ edges, so at most $2^{10n}$ perfect matchings [see case 1].

Comment: Great.  In which case the genus is greater than $n$ [see case 2].

Comment: Are you hoping for a construction or a lower bound?  If the genus is too small, there are not many edges at all (at most linearly many).  And if there are only $cn$ edges, the number of perfect matchings is at most $2^{cn}$, which is in fact less than $2^{cn \log(g)}$.  This is a better upper bound than what you were hoping for.  So there is no lower bound matching the upper bound hoped for in OP.

Comment: I admit I’m confused by your objection.  Perhaps we could continue in chat?

Comment: A graph with $E$ edges certainly has at most $2^E$ perfect matchings (it has that many subgraphs).  And if a graph has genus less than $n$, then it has fewer than $10n$ edges.  When the genus is small, the upper bound $2^{10n}$ holds.  Note!  This is smaller than $2^{10n\log(g)}$.  So it is not possible to get $2^{10n\log(g)}$ perfect matchings unless $g \geq n$, in which case we can’t have more than $n! \leq 2^{10 n \log(n)} \leq 2^{10 n \log(g)}$ perfect matchings.  (The $n!$ is just a silly upper bound on the number of perfect matchings of the complete graph.)

Comment: (Commenting on “all or nothing” comment) Yea.  Seems like it.  The upper bounds of $2^{E}$ and $n!$ are always smaller than $2^{n \log(g)}$.  I think one of the morals here is that “logs and tolerable multiplicative factors in the exponent cover a multitude of sin.”

Comment: Is there reference for genus lower bound?

Comment: It’s just the same exact argument showing planar graphs don’t have that many edges (use Euler’s formula and double count edges and faces).  See the “Euler’s formula” portion of the wiki page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph

Comment: Page $18$ http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs6204/files/Lec2-Min&MaxGenus.pdf refers.

Comment: Posted https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332834/grading-of-biadjacency-permanent-with-respect-to-genus-of-graph.